Can't install Tensorflow in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I'm trying to install TensorFlow on my Ubuntu system, but I'm encountering some issues. Here's what I've done and the issues I'm facing:
1. sudo apt install python3-tensorflow:
This command returns the error:
E: Unable to locate package python3-tensorflow

It seems the python3-tensorflow package might not be available in the default repositories for my Ubuntu version or architecture.
2. pip3 install tensorflow and sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow:
Both commands result in the following error:
error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed

This suggests my system's Python environment is configured to prevent pip from installing packages system-wide, likely for security reasons.
My Goal:
My primary goal is to install TensorFlow on my local system, ideally without creating a virtual environment.
Question:
Given the errors I'm encountering, what's the recommended approach to install TensorFlow on my system? Is there any solution for this problem. All my packages are up to date.
